# Ext.require php file

Tags: php, extjs

I have a php file that genereates a js.
When I try with:

```
ext.require('path/file.php');
```

I get the error:

```
Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading synchronously via XHR: 'path/file/php.js'; please verify that the file exists. XHR status code: 404
```

The problem is I have file.php and ext tries to get file/php.js

How can I make it try to get the correct file?

Comment: without knowing your folder structure, we won't know the problem

Comment: The folder structure is OK 
The problem is I have file.php and ext tries to get file/php.js everthing before the file is OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Set path for your file alias in Ext.Loader config:

   ```
   Ext.Loader.setPath({
       'someAlias': 'path/file.php'
   });
   Ext.require('someAlias');
   ```
2. Use [Ext.Loader.loadScript()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript):

   ```
   Ext.Loader.loadScript({
       url: 'path/file.php'
   });
   ```

Comment: Works great, I had the same question. Funny this is marked as "too localized".